# Xcode showing unsupported os version for iOS 16.2 devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, flutter

When I connect iOS device with 16.2 OS version.

Xcode shows unsupported OS version.

Because I don't have the device support files for iOS 16.2

So how can I download the device support files for iOS 16.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download device support files at https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport but if you want to get 16.2 then it should be enough to download the latest version of Xcode. I have iOS version 16.2 and have version of Xcode 14.2 (14C18).

Answer (score 2):

Without updating Xcode, you need to put the relevant device file in the DeviceSupport section and run Xcode again. DeviceSupport files are located here.use this command

```
cd /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
```

You can download iOS 16.2 devicesupport file from [here](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport), then you need to unzip (download 16.0 and rename it to 16.2), then you need to put it in DeviceSupport section on your mac.

When you restart Xcode, there should be no problem.

Comment: This still holds true but the GitHub repo is a little behind. It only goes to 16.5 at the time I'm writing this. I had to download 16.6 from another place. Also, for those of us who are stuck developing on older mac's circa 2016, we are unable to update to the latest Xcode without buying a new Mac. This download method gives us a little room to develop while waiting for a new Mac.